# Right Join in SQL Server is taking too long

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    b.1, b.2, b.3, b.4, a.4, a.3, a.5
FROM 
    a 
RIGHT JOIN
    b ON a.id = b.id
```

This query is taking more than 7 minutes.

Both tables have around 100 000 records and just a select from each table runs around 12 seconds avg. In execution plan it is saying that table a has logical reads of around 8708 and 100% operator cost. Both tables have CI on ID.

Comment: Ew a right join. Try this:

Comment: Your query would generate a syntax error (there is no `b`).  It also (probably) generates lots and lots of data.  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: u are using both same tables FROM a right join a on a.id = b.id

Comment: Gordon : Its typo. there should be 'b' after right join.

Comment: Joins don't take a lot of time. Queries without proper indexes though, *do* take a lot of time. Post the execution plane, the schema of the tables and any indexes defined on them. Otherwise this question will have to be closed - there is *no* relevant information.

Comment: PS, using column indexes instead of names is just asking for trouble and returning the *wrong* column. Are you sure you aren't returning a BLOB by mistake? How many rows are there in the tables? What are the sizes and types of the columns?

Comment: Another possible problem could be that the `ID` columns are text columns with different collations instead of `int` or `bigint`. Indexes can't be used when joining tables of different collations because one of the columns has to be converted to a different collation

Answer (score 0):

Verify that an `INDEX` on the `ID` column exists in table `A`. For each row selected in `B` there will be a lookup of rows in `A` on the `ID` column. If an index does not exist on that column this will result in a table scan i.e. a lookup through 100k rows to find rows with that specific `ID`. Not efficient.

---

PS - General advice: write queries that don't use `RIGHT JOIN`, stick to `INNER`, `LEFT` and `OUTER` joins unless there is no other way (there almost always is).

Answer (score 0):

Use this sql below to help you identify any missing indexes.  My guess is you are missing at least one.

```
SELECT 
statement AS [database.scheme.table],
column_id , column_name, column_usage, 
migs.user_seeks, migs.user_scans, 
migs.last_user_seek, migs.avg_total_user_cost,
migs.avg_user_impact
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_details AS mid
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_missing_index_columns (mid.index_handle)
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups AS mig 
ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats  AS migs 
ON mig.index_group_handle=migs.group_handle
ORDER BY mig.index_group_handle, mig.index_handle, column_id
```